# Android Device Drivers: not found?

Tags: android, drivers

I followed the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) to install my Android device drivers (Windows 7) so I can run apps on my real device instead of an emulator.

What should one do when Windows is unable to find the drivers you need and install them (...\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver)?

I did browse the internet, but my manufacturer seems "underground" and I couldn't find any trustable links.

Concretely, my device's name is "Qualcomm HSUSB device", T-mobile MOVE 2.2.2 version.

Comment: i had the same issue with an allview phone , i didn't find the drivers available anywhere because the chinese manufacturers didn't distribute them nor is the reseller willing to share the drivers ... not sure what to say in this case

Comment: I'm guessing my only choice is to buy a better phone and work on an emulator until then.

Comment: well if adb isn't working ... i'd probably go ask the reseller or manufacturer for drivers ... or have a go towards http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: If your phone is actually the Alcatel OT-908 (seems the MOVE is a rebrand) , [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1467676) xda post might come in handy. It talks about rooting, but it does provide adb drivers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all in the ADT you need to tick `Google Usb Driver` for install 
then if your device is an Samsung model you need to download and install `Samsung Kies`
and if your device is an HTC you need `HTC manager` etc ..

these links may help you:

[Android: Debugging your application on real hardware (phone/tablet) on Ubuntu 10.10](http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-debugging-your-application-on.html)

[Android debugging on real device](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-debugging-on-real-device/)

see the second one I think that may help you ..